# mail() function doesn't appear to be working

Tags: php

I am using the following code to try and send an email - I can't see any problem with it - but it's not working, it displays the message "email sent" but I don't receive anything.

```
<?php
$to = "email@address.com";
$subject = "Query";
$message_body.="Name: ".$_POST["name"]."<br>\n";
$message_body.="JobTitle: ".$_POST["jobtitle"]."<br>\n";
$message_body.="Phone: ".$_POST["phone"]."<br>\n";
$message_body.="Email: ".$_POST["email"]."<br>\n";
$header = "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html;
mail($to, $subject,  $message_body, $header);
echo "Email sent";
?>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Of course it displays "Email sent" as you never check if it was actually sent. According to the [manual](http://www.php.net/mail) of `mail`: *Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise.*

Comment: And watch out for mail header injection, never trust user content! And mail headers should be newlined using `\r\n`.

Comment: Start by removing your `<br>`'s

Answer (score 2):

Check 1) For the mail functions to be available, PHP requires an installed and working email system. The program to be used is defined by the configuration settings in the php.ini file.

You mentioned that there are no errors.. so next..

Check 2) Check the return value of function.. TRUE or FALSE

Check 3) See if any warning by enabling error_reporting(E_ALL)

Check 4) Actually mail sent, but went to Spam folder.

> For mail() , it is important to note that just because the mail was
>   accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach
>   the intended destination.

Also there is a difference in a way how it works in Windows and Unix.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is missing a " in the last $header line

try adding:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors","On");
```

at the beginning of the file to show the errors / warnings you get. Most likely sendmail is not running on your server

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your SMTP server configuration.
http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

Probably it blocks your mail.